# Making a chain of p's flow into a "two-page spread"

Tags: css, pagination, overflow

Recently a student got this quite by accident (or well, a side effect of incorrect xhtml/css). Is this possible to do in a cross-browser, automatic way with say a Wordpress article and custom html/css? (I.e., no php script or such.)

It's been a goal for me to at one point make a site that reads "like a book" rather than a scroll.

Ideas?

Edit: I should make the goal clear. It is to write a text with pictures using f.ex. TinyMCE or the like, and present it with typography and layout quality and 'overviewability' of classic technical magazines such as the early BYTE spreads, or science folios. I'll accept a php solution if no CSS trick will handle the overflow automatically. What I want to 'get rid of' is the need to manually chop up the say 5-page article into columns.

Perhaps LyX can generate out decent HTML with 1 file per 2-page spread? That would be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS 3 allows flowing "newspaper columns" if that is what you mean.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

<s>Most current</s> At least Gecko and Webkit based browsers support it, but may require vendor-specific prefixes:

http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/

Comment: Yes, bar cunning paragraph-splitting PHP gymnastics, this looks the best for the moment. First part of this article pretty much well covers where my thinking comes from: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css3multicolumn

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like this:

```
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2</p>
<p>text3</p>
<p>text4</p>
```

And give the following style:

```
p { float: left; }
```

It should place each P side by side. However, how many P's go side by side depends on how much width is available, so if you define that each P take, say 200px, and the total width in the container is 400px, the end result would be two P's side by side, something like this:

```
text1 text2
text3 text4
```

Do note that this will not look so good (or work so well) if the contents of the P's aren't about the same length. I don't think there's a neat way of doing it just with CSS if you need the sizes to automatically split into such columns as well.

As a side note, I've seen some sites which do this. *It's not really a that good idea*. It works on paper and magazines, but not so well on screen in my experience. Unless I'm mistaken, there have also been some studies about this coming to the same conclusion.

Comment: Thanks. The point was 'handle the overflow' though, if you know what I mean. The curious mistake by the student was probably something to the effect of what you describe, since the example paragraph text were three 'lorem ipsum' paragraphs, and then it would look right since they're of equal length. Regarding not a good idea, I will add the general goal to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As Jani says I'm not sure 2 column layout works very well in web, because of the way people generally read on the web.  I would personally not recommend a 2 column layout for articles like that for a web site.

Also I am not sure there is anyway you could create that without using dynamic scripting, unless you dictate the amount of copy for each section, otherwise it would be spectacularly easy for the user to give miss matched columns.

Comment: I accept your view, even though I don't subscribe to 'existing standard way became standard so people got used to it and now they can't handle anything else', if you know what I mean. I think everyone is capable of reading a two-page spread, a multi-column newspaper article, PDFs etc (not to mention they already do it all the time, thinking nothing of it). But it would be helpful if the height was fixed, certainly. It's a choice between overview/maximum content-presentation versus scrolling a 1000px wide text forever... widescreen displays are much more suited to the former.

Comment: Yes, but I think that applying print logic to the web is fundamentally flawed, because it is a completely different medium and the way people read and interact with a web page is not the same as how some one interacts with a piece of print.  The other thing to be careful of is making the gross assumption that someone will be looking at it in a fabulous high res screen, because that isn't the case.  They could be looking at it in netbook, tablet, or even a smart phone, you can't guarantee.  That's not to say we can't learn somethings from print but you need to be careful about how you apply it.

Comment: I accept your opinion, but I think if I followed it I would catch the same amount of flak if I adapted the content to the least (smallest) common denominator. If a phone is to claim merit for use as a surf pad, it should adapt itself to the pages found on the web, which in turn should be laid out according to the content it is to present. Certainly my layout is better for my content than the standard no-structure blog or webpage which already has 3 columns, two of which are filled with irrelevant junk.